# Добавить или обновить документ в MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

В бд есть несколько документов. Каким методом mongoose можно добавить новые, а если у них совпадают уникальные поля, то обновить эти документы?

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    siteID: {
       type: String,
       unique: true,
    },
    sex: {
        type: String,
    },
    subcategory: {
        type: String,
    });
```

А добавляю я так:

```
return Promise.all(prod.map(product => {
                 return Product.create({
                     siteID: product[0],
                     sex: product[1],
                     subcategory: product[2],

                 })
             }))
```

Понятно, что сейчас он выкидывает ошибку и не добавляет документы с одинаковым siteID.

А мне нужно что бы документы с одинаковым siteID обновлялись, а другие добавлялись в БД.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` с `upsert : true`?

Comment: @Yaant  Получается нужно последовательно добавлять каждый документ? Сначала искать его, если есть, то обновлять (findOneAndUpdate), а если нет, то добавлять (create)? Это достаточно оптимальное решение? Я просто думал что есть какие то готовые решения для таких манипуляций.

Comment: Нет. Я же написал, надо выставить опцию `upsert` в `true`, тогда, если документ не найден, он будет создан.

Comment: @Yaant ! Спасибо))